# Textbox Array connected MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im new in using vb.net and mysql queries and i cant find the right solution to my problem here.
i have 10 textboxes and i want to fill it with 10 questions from my database but the code below fills only the first textbox with the last question

```
        Dim txtQ() As TextBox = {txtQ1, txtQ2, txtQ3}
        Dim r As MySqlDataReader
        Dim i As Integer
          con.Open()
          cmd = New MySqlCommand("select * from tbexam", con)
          r = cmd.ExecuteReader

          For i = 0 To 9
            While r.Read
                txtQ(i).Text = r.GetString("exam_question")
            End While

          Next
          con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will help you

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While r.Read
        If i <= 9 Then
            txtQ(i).Text = r.GetString("exam_question")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End While
```